# Selecting the next available number in a row

Tags: php

If i have a database like this one

```
[ id  -    post  -  num ]
[  1        P1       1  ]
[  2        P2       2  ]
[  3        P3       3  ]
[  4        P4       5  ]
[  5        P5       7  ]
```

Now i have a code like this

```
$max_number = 7; // AFTER QUERY
$current_number = $_GET['num']; // = 1

if($current_number < $max_number){
echo "<a href='#'>The {$current_number++} in rating Post</a>";
}
```

the problem in this code that if the topic number is 3 and clicked it would give me number 4 which doesn't  exist, Is there a possible way to do it better? using array if possible.

Comment: You need a pagination script for this.

Comment: @Fred-ii- can't see how a pagination script would work with that, I thought about calling all the numbers in array then selecting it 1 by 1, But can't figure that out either.

Comment: alrighty, well I am not the guy for arrays, sorry. I thought pagination would have suited this.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Same as you here, But write an example about using pagination script for this if possible, Maybe it would be better and easier than arrays.

Comment: You can order the array by element `num` and then loop over it and `if num > 3 // logic`. So, since you'd order it by num, you'd get 5 as the next element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution could be (in sql, you will have to implement it):

```
SELECT MIN(num) FROM tab WHERE num>$current_number;
```

This would give you your previous `($current_number++)` value.

Answer (score 0):

Store all available number in an array something like this

```
$available_numbers= arrray(1,2,3,5,6,7);
```

Change some code according to your need.

```
<?php
$available_numbers= array(1,2,3,5,6,7);
$max_number = 7; // AFTER QUERY
$current_number = 1; // = 1
do{
    if(in_array($current_number, $available_numbers)){
        echo "<a href='#'>The {$current_number} in rating Post</a>";
    }
    $current_number++;
}while($current_number < $max_number);
?>
```